Is there a guide to configure a content delivery server for Sitecore 10?
Back in the days of Sitecore 8, Sitecore used to have a page with a list of recommendations about how to configure a Content Delivery server, like this:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/configure-a-content-delivery-server.html#configure-a-content-delivery-server-1
That page even provided a link to an Excel file that was used as a guide to activate/deactivate different .config files depending on the features needed.
My question:
Is there something similar for Sitecore 10?
I've been searching on the official Sitecore documentation sites, but haven't found anything equivalent.
Any pointers or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

In Sitecore 10, there isn't an exact equivalent of the Excel file or the detailed list of recommendations for setting up a Content Delivery server that existed for Sitecore 8. However, the process for configuring environments remains similar. You still need to enable or disable specific configurations depending on the server role you're working with.
In Sitecore 10, rule-based configuration simplifies the process of setting up server roles by defining specific keys in the web.config. The predefined roles include ContentDelivery, ContentManagement, and more. You can also combine roles, though combinations like ContentManagement with xDB Processing are allowed, while mixing ContentDelivery and ContentManagement is not advised for production. Custom rules can be added for more control, such as environment-specific configurations.
Hope this helps.

This Excel file is no longer required, Sitecore now uses rule-based configuration and necessary config files are enabled and disabled depending on the server role. You just need to make sure that each server is using the correct role in web.config like this:
<appSettings>
   <add key="role:define" value="ContentDelivery"/>
</appSettings>

You can read more about scaling and configuring Content Delivery roles in the documentation here.

You can find the details on configuring and scaling Sitecore Content Delivery role on the Sitecore documentation here that provide different packages to setup this role.
All the configurations are now handled on the servers using rule-based configuration inside Web.config file that decides which configuration should be loaded.
 <add key="role:define" value="ContentDelivery" />

You can find more details for the role based configuration here.
Note: After Sitecore version 8, there were various roles introduced apart from core roles for managing XDB data such as xConnect Collection, xConnect Search, processing and reporting role. These roles can be scaled independently.
Hope this helps.
